# Where to find a detailed documentation of Superset REST API to create a chart/dashboard?

Tags: rest, apache-superset, api-documentation

I am trying to use Superset API using the [official documentation](https://superset.apache.org/docs/api/). The first step was to manually create a chart in the UI and analyzing the traffic. I copied the payload of the POST /api/v1/chart endpoint and used it to send a payload via the REST API. That works fine.

The problem is: I don't understand the payload I send to the endpoint. Is there a documentation for more details? Especially the field "params" and "query_context".

I already tried searching in google and the superset github page. Also using phind.com. I didn't got an answer.